# How to determine which neurons to connect between layers in an artificial neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Say for my first input layer I have 10 input nodes/neurons. Say my hidden layer has 10 neurons as well. My third and final layer is one output neuron.

How do I connect the layers? Is there a technique for determining the best way to do this or do you just connect each input neuron to each of the hidden layer neurons for a total of 100 edges between the two layers?

This is probably a really basic question but I haven't seen too many concrete examples. The examples I did find either seem to connect all the neurons or the connections seem randomized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything, this is based on intuition and empirical results. I've seen people use recursive neural networks.

With a *feedforward neural network*, it makes sense to connect all neurons from layer `n` to all neurons in layer `n+1`.

Here is an example from my latest usage (to demonstrate the enormous amount of edges):

[image: Neural network]

Comment: Did you decide how many layers to use and how many neurons to have in each hidden layer through testing and intuition as well? Is it a feed forward neural network if you're given training sets and have to back propagate to adjust for errors?

Comment: I've tested several arrangements, and the current setup worked best for my use-case. Feedforward networks use the back propagation algorithm (along with, say, gradient descent or Newton-Raphson) to adjust weights.

Comment: In your diagram there are nodes which are not connected to input layer (neither directly nor indirectly) but are connected (directly or indirectly) to output layer. Does this make sense? How? (Example: 1st hidden layer, upper node)

Comment: Those are called the bias nodes. Their input value is always fixed at a constant value, but the connection weight is trained as per usual. Some literature seems to indicate this is a good idea, other seem to disagree. In essence it allows one layer or neuron to become 'suddenly' more dominant.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you cut some links between input nodes and hidden layer, you're artificially affecting the training phase. Basically **you're giving more importance to the remaining links**.

*Even if you connect one neuron with only a fraction of the neurons in the next layer, it's like having them all connected but the communication weight is 0 for non connected neurons*. The training algorithm may actually reach this situation.

What it really matters is the architecture of the neural network and the weights assigned to each input / output links of the neuron.

So connect each of the 10 input nodes of the input layer to all the 10 nodes in the hidden layer, and **let the training algorithm do its job**. If you have enough training and testing data, it will produce expected results.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that all nodes in adjacent layers should be connected.  So all 10 input nodes should connect to all 10 nodes in the hidden layer (100 connections).  Then all 10 nodes in the hidden layer should connect to the output node (10 connections).

In your case I believe the total number of connections should be 110.